# clearTimeout if exists

Tags: javascript

`timer_gear` exist only in case if I press some button (until 5 sec). But there is another function it can be called any time. In this function I clear the timer and restart it. But first I have to check if the object exists otherwise I get this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: timer_gear is not defined

Could you help me to solve this? These does not work.

```
if(timer_gear!="undefined")clearTimeout(timer_gear);

if(timer_gear)clearTimeout(timer_gear);
```

EDIT1:
first I misspelled my question: if(!timer => if(timer
EDIT2:

the full code is:

```
function hide_gear(){
    $('#gear_div').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
    delete timer_gear; //EDIT3: destroy object
}
```

...

```
/*gear*/
$('#gear').click(function(){
    $('#gear_div').animate({
        opacity: 1,
      }, 1000, function() {
        timer_gear = setTimeout("hide_gear();",5000);
      });
});
$('#gear').mousemove(function(){
    if( ? ? ? )
    {
        clearTimeout(timer_gear);
        timer_gear = setTimeout("hide_gear();",5000);
    }

});
```

### Results:

```
timer_gear// Uncaught ReferenceError timer_gear is not defined
timer_gear != undefined // Uncaught ReferenceError: timer_gear is not defined
typeof timer_gear !== "undefined" // WORKS
typeof timer_gear != "undefined" // WORKS, just tired it
var timer_gear; //at the begining - WORKS, but I did not wanted a new variable if its not necessary
```

thank you for answers!

Comment: What is "does not work"? Present a better analysis of how the observed behaviour differs from the expected behaviour.

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing globals around like that.  Use `var` to declare variables.

Comment: P.S. You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`, they get `eval`d, you should pass functions.  `setTimeout(hide_gear,5000);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st one should be:

```
if(typeof timer_gear !== "undefined"){
  clearTimeout(timer_gear);
}
```

And the 2nd, but this *won't work* if `timer_gear` is not defined, **so you should use the `typeof` one above**:

```
if(timer_gear){
  clearTimeout(timer_gear);
}
```

Answer (score 64):

All you need to do is declare `timer_gear`. `clearTimeout` is not the problem here. To quote the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout); Passing an invalid ID to `clearTimeout` does not have any effect (and doesn't throw an exception). So just add the following to the top of your code:

```
var timer_gear;
```

No need for all the if's that everyone else is suggesting.

Comment: This answer right here is the one you want.  No ifs needed, the problem you're encountering is that the value undefined and an undefined thing are different things.

Comment: An updated link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Comment: @ziyuang thank you for that. I updated my question to use the updated link you provided.

Answer (score 7):

If you only want to clear the timer held in the variable `timer_gear` if it exists, you can do

```
if (timer_gear) clearTimeout(timer_gear);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different condition on your `if`:

```
if (typeof(timer_gear) !== "undefined")
```

or simply:

```
if (timer_gear)
```

Comment: first one world. Second one doesn't if timer_gear is not yet declared (var timer_gear), or set (timer_gear=false). It would still raise a ReferenceError exception

Comment: Point. I guess I just automatically assumed it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that should work:

```
timer_gear = false;
if(timer_gear != false){
    clearTimeout(timer_gear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(timer_gear)clearTimeout(timer_gear);
```

or

```
if(timer_gear != undefined)clearTimeout(timer_gear);
```